# Stripping variables of hashtag in SCSS before using them in selectors?

Tags: sass

Another problem here.. my team wants to use borders in different widths, colors and positions. So, I made this:

```
$position-list: top right bottom left;
$colors-list: fff ccc ddd eee;


 @for $i from 1 through 3 {
   @each $position in $position-list {
        @each $color in $colors-list {
            .border-#{$position}-#{$i}-#{$color} {
                border-#{$position}: #{$i}px solid #{"#"}#{$color} !important;
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

This works great, however, I want to include the colors as variables from my colors.scss sheet ($light-color, $dark-color etc). The problem is that the hashtags from the colors.scss sheet will be transfered as well ($dark-color: #000), so it will most likely generate a weird selector (.border-top-1-#000) or doesn't compile at all.

Is there a way of stripping the variables from the colors.scss sheet of their hashtags before putting them in the selector? Or does anyone have a different/better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert the color to a string ([`#inspect`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Value/Color.html#inspect-instance_method)) and slice it ([`#str-slice`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#str_slice-instance_method)).

```
$dark-color: #000;
$light-color: #fff;
$abc-color: #abc;

$position-list: top right bottom left;
$colors-list: $dark-color $light-color $abc-color;

@for $i from 1 through 3 {
    @each $position in $position-list {
        @each $color in $colors-list {
            $stripped-color: str-slice(inspect($color), 2);
            .border-#{$position}-#{$i}-#{$stripped-color} {
                border-#{$position}: #{$i}px solid #{$color} !important;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output (example):

```
.border-top-1-abc {
    border-top: 1px solid #abc !important;
}
```