# Gulp Sass Expected identifier

Tags: sass, gulp

Can anyone help with this gulp-sass error.
I'm trying to run Google's code labs which includes package gulp-sass.

```
[01:02:31] 'build:scss' errored after 117 ms
[01:02:31] Error in plugin "gulp-sass"
Message:
    app/styles/_categories.scss
Error: Expected identifier.
   ╷
50 │   %bg-#4285f4{
   │        ^
   ╵
  app/styles/_categories.scss 50:8    codelab-card()
  app/styles/_categories.scss 79:1    @import
  app/styles/_codelab-card.scss 18:9  @import
  app/styles/main.scss 22:9           root stylesheet
Details:
    formatted: Error: Expected identifier.
   ╷
50 │   %bg-#4285f4{
   │        ^
```

Comment: Class names can only include the hash character if it's escaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encountered this problem when trying to run gulp-sass to serve the Google Codelabs [example site](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tools/tree/main/site)

### The problem

The [sass interpolation syntax](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation) in line 50 looks like this:

```
%bg-#{$color}
```

Which unwraps `$color` inplace, yielding

```
.bg-#XXXXXX
```

Notice that the character '#' is an invalid indentifier in css

### The fix

Convert the color to a string and then strip out the hex value (As explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55001515/stripping-variables-of-hashtag-in-scss-before-using-them-in-selectors))

```
$stripped-color: str-slice(inspect($color), 2);

%bg-#{$stripped-color} {
    background-color: $color;
}
...
```